# MySql - Select from - Don't Show Duplicate Words - maybe "on duplicate key"?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

how can I insert "on duplicate key" in this Code to remove duplicate words? or is there a better method that you know? thank you!!

this is my code:

```
function sm_list_recent_searches($before = '', $after = '', $count = 20) {
// List the most recent successful searches.
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $count = intval($count);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT `terms`, `datetime`
        FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
        WHERE 3 < `hits` AND CHAR_LENGTH(`terms`) > 4
        ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
        LIMIT $count");
    if (count($results)) {

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<a href="'. get_settings('home') . '/search/' . urlencode($result->terms) . '">'. htmlspecialchars($result->terms) .'</a>'.", ";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is used to cause an insert to update records if they already exist. It's not used for `SELECT` queries

What you want is to use the `GROUP BY` clause on your terms column to collapse it to unique values. You can use the `MAX` aggregate function to get the date of the latest record for those terms.

```
SELECT `terms`, MAX(`datetime`)
FROM `{$table_prefix}searchmeter_recent`
WHERE 3 < `hits` AND CHAR_LENGTH(`terms`) > 4
GROUP BY terms
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
LIMIT $count
```

Make sure you have an index on the terms column, otherwise this will be a very expensive operation, especially if you're using it to make an autocomplete. You might even consider grouping your terms at insert time for best performance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using the distinct keyword in your query?  This shows what it does: http://newsourcemedia.com/blog/mysql-distinct-to-remove-duplicate-listing/

Comment: DISTINCT will affect all columns, so terms with different datetime values will still be repeated. What you want is GROUP BY.